# Sharing Internet Connection using an ad-hoc wifi network

Tags: windows-xp, internet-connection, connection-sharing, ad-hoc-network

I've installed a WiFi Adapter in my Windows XP PC and created an ad-hoc network. I am able to connect to the network through my iPod Touch. 

On the same PC I have a LAN connection to the Internet. I need to share this internet connection to my iPod too. The problem is Windows did not assign an IP Address (even though `assign IP address automatically` is selected) to this WiFi network.
When I tried to share the Internet connection, I got a message that `LAN Network Adapter's IP address will be changed to 192.168.1.1`. But if this
happens I will not be able to connect to other devices/servers in my LAN Network.

**Also I see that I don't have the option to share the Internet connection on my actual LAN connection. I see this option only for WIFI Connection.**

How do I share the Internet connection through WiFi?